# How to convert pixels to inches using PptxGenJs library?

Tags: pptxgenjs

Need help. I am using PptxGenJs library. I want to convert Html pixels to Ppt inches, I tried slide methods.

Sample code:

```
slide.addText('some message', {
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  w: 10,
  h: 3
});
```

what does mean 'x: 1, y: 1' and 'w: 10, h: 3'?